# Use packages from old R-Version in new R-Version with renv

Tags: r, renv

I'm using `renv` i.e. for package management in R-projects. I cannot load packages from external sources. After a new R-Version was installed, I want to continue using **the same packages** in the new version as used in the old R-version.

Since `renv` creates a new directory to store packages for the new R-version (e.g. `.../renv/library/R-4.2/`), which contains only "base" packages installed with the new R-version, I want to "clone" the packages stored in the `renv` environment of the old R-version (e.g. `.../renv/library/R-4.1/`).

What is the best practice to simply use the same packages in the new R-version compared to the old R-version (without installing packages). Using `renv::restore()`, `renv` tries to newly install packages for the new R-version (and I don't want this). Can I simply "copy" the content of `.../renv/library/R-4.1/` to `.../renv/library/R-4.2/`? Does `renv` provide options to simply keep using packages from "old R-versions" (here R-4.1) in "new R-versions" (here R-4.2)?

Comment: Some package are compiled and expect certain R APIs to be available. It's generally not a safe idea so just copy over packages build for different versions of R. You should be able to reinstall the same package version number in each version of R (if minimum R version requirements are met) but those will need to be in two separate libraries on disk.